# How to get and disect the query string appended into a url? PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a PHP class which would enable me to get the query string appended into a url and process it according to the variables passed. How can this be done?

Eg

```
www.example.com?var1=a&var2=b&var3=c
```

now I want to get `?var1=a&var2=b&var3=c` section and process it based on the variables.

Thanks for your responses

but I want a means by which I can get the whole query string since I wont be sure of the variable names that will be sent into the URL thus the $_GET method wont work properly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about URLs with which you access your site or URLs contained in a string (from e.g. a database)?

Comment: I am talking about the URLs used to access your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want access to the URL parameters as a string you can use this:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

But, I'm not sure how that would be any more useful than `$_GET`. You said:

> I wont be sure of the variable names

You can iterate through the `$_GET` array with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ": " . $val;
}
```

However... if you're talking about an *arbitrary* URL (not necessarily the one which was requested), then the above methods won't work since they obviously won't be in `$_GET`. Instead you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
arg=value
```

Comment: +1 for the awesome varieties presented.  This should do everything the OP requested and more.  I had forgotten about a couple of the options mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Current URL: www.example.com?var1=a&var2=b&var3=c
function handleUrl()
{
    $var1 = $_GET['var1']; // now contains 'a'
    $var2 = $_GET['var2']; // now contains 'b'
    $var3 = $_GET['var3']; // now contains 'c'

    return "Querystring now contains $var1 $var2 and $var3";
}
```

More information at
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: but dont forget to htmlspecialchars() the $_GET, because otherwise people can use xss to "hack" your site or to use it for bad things :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [$_GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the parameters stored in a variable, then use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Example:

```
$str = 'var1=a&var2=b&var3=c';
parse_str($str);
echo $var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) is the function you're probably looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalistic class. It should work, but it is not tested.

```
<?php
class URLHandler 
{
    public $get;

    public function __construct( $get );
    {
        $this->get = $get;
    }

    public function get_var( $var )
    {
        return htmlspecialchars( $this->get[$var] );
    }

    public function check_var( $var, $is )
    {
        if( $this->get_var( $var ) == $is )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// Below is how you can use this class
$URL = new URLHandler( $_GET );
if( $URL->check_var( 'var1', 'a' ) )
{
    echo 'yes your first var is a';
    // Here you can add a function or functions which should be loaded if var1 = a
}
else
{
    echo 'No, your first var is not a, its '.$URL->get_var( 'var2' );
    // Here you can add a function or functions which should be loaded if var1 is not a
}

if( $URL->check_var( 'var2', 'a' ) )
{
    echo 'and your second var is a';
}
else
{
    echo 'your second var is not a, its '.$URL->get_var( 'var2' );
}
?>
```